# IIS accessing resources via logged in user and NOT pool identity. How to enforce POOL Identity

Tags: windows-authentication, applicationpoolidentity

I have a classic asp website with following IIS settings:

1. windows authentication is enabled

2. Impersonation is disabled, so are anonymous and basic authentication

3. App pool is .Net 4.0, Integrated pipeline with a custom Process model identity. This identityt is given exclusive full access to unc local and network shares, batch files etc

The asp application 

1. displays user information of the user logging intot he web application,

2. accesses the above mentioned shares to display reports,

3. creates reports by calling DLLs which POST to an asp file in this web application (uing webrequest) and get XMl and write the XML to the share.

The issue I am facing is all the above calls are being made on the behalf of the application user instead of the Process Model Identity User in the app pool. Because of this, most of requests throw up Permission denied or 401 errors. 

**QUESTION**: How can we configure the web site so that the calls made can be on behalf of the app pool user only?